# Add hook after registration form submit

Tags: 7, forms

I'm trying to club Drupal & Magento together. So I want to make the registration seamless. If any user register in Drupal they want to register in Magento automatically using a custom module in Drupal. I have scripts to register in Magento by sending data to Magento script file.

I want to know how to make a AJAX call to that script file, using a custom Drupal module. I'm using Drupal 7 version.

Comment: I also want to pass registration form data in the ajax call.

Comment: You can try http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: This is php curl by default to get response from the page. My Question is how to add a hook after registration form submit in drupal framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For achieving this goal you have to Implement drupal [hook_user_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7.x)
and Use php [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [hook_user_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7.x), in which you can easily execute CURL, in hook_user_insert you will have all your data regarding the user.